# what is the best free/open source WinForms "progress bar" control?

Tags: winforms, open-source, controls, progress-bar

what is the best free/open source WinForms "progress bar" control?

(i.e. want a better looking control than the default one in VS2008, and one that has a nice continuous bar)

PS I'm pretty new to .net so I'm not sure at all if there are any popular control libraries (open source) that are widely used or not...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One of the nice things about Windows Forms is that you'll usually get the new look of the common controls on a new version of Windows.  That certainly applies to ProgressBar, on Vista and Win7 you get the green continuous bar with the traveling highlight note.  No code is required.

If you now see a blocky blue bar then you've either got a really old version of Windows or you've got visual styles turned off.  Looking for a replacement for PB is, frankly, a waste of time, look for a replacement of Windows.  I recommend Win7.

Comment: Oh. We're still stuck on XP at the moment :(

I assume it's the target PC that is the issue, not the PC you use to compile the winforms app?

Comment: Right, the target PC.  If your customer is also stuck on XP then she won't mind seeing the normal progress bar.  However, if she moved up, she'll *really* want to see the fancy Vista bar, not a replacement you made.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Krypton controls](http://www.componentfactory.com/)'s progressbar or [Progress-O-Doom](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/progress/ProgressODoom.aspx)

Comment: AFAICT, [Krypton suite](https://github.com/ComponentFactory/Krypton) doesn't include a progressbar control.